# How can I create a view from more than one table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-view

I have to create a view from more than one table in an MS SQL Server database, but I am not able to get the correct syntax for the same.

Comment: Could you please post your view syntax? That would give us a place to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to provide more information about how you are looking to return data from more than one table.  Typically you use JOINs:

```
CREATE VIEW your_view_vw AS
   SELECT *
     FROM TABLE_A a
     JOIN TABLE_B b ON b.pk = a.fk
```

...where `fk` stands for "Foreign Key", and `pk` stands for "Primary Key" - assuming these constraints are in place.  Maybe you need to use a Cross join instead?  Here's a [great visual representation of JOINs visually](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Reference:

- [CREATE VIEW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You do this with JOINs, just like you would with a regular query.

If you can write a query that gets you the data, you should be able to write view nearly the exact same way.

Post what you have.

Answer (score 1):

example

```
create view ViewCustomerOrders
as
select * from Customer c
join Order o on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create view viewname
as
select * from table a
join table b on b.col2 = a.col2
```

Answer (score 0):

create view view_name
as 
select * from table_A a
join table_B b on a.column_id = b.column_id