# retrieve information from multiple tables

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

I have 3 tables, called Drivers, Offences and Points and Sofar I'm using 3 sql Strings to insert and update data in the tables

```
String command1 = "INSERT INTO Drivers (IDNumber, FirstName, LastName) VALUES" + drivID + FName + LName;
String command2 = "INSERT INTO Offences(IDNumber, SpeedLimit, DriverSpeed, SeatBelt, DrunkenDriving, DriversLicense) VALUES" + drivID + intspeed + intDSpeed + strSeat + strDrunk + strLicense;
String command3 = "INSERT INTO DriverPoints(IDNumber, Points) VALUES" + drivID + intpoints;
```

Each table is coneccted to eachother through the primary key IDNumber

Is there a way instead of having 3 Sql commands/Strings where I can have only 1 but still be able to insert and update all 3 tables?

Comment: First of all, all your 3 queries are syntactically incorrect. Secondly, why would you need to have them in single string variable? As that will not at all reduce you typing. I would suggest you to first practice with single query per string.

Comment: You can read all together via join, but you'll have to handle it. which database are you using?

Comment: I have text boxes and checkboxes in a java application that I want update the using the info from the database and update the data in the database by also using the same controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughtly your query should look like this:

```
SELECT d.IDNumber, d.FirstName, d.LastName, o.SpeedLimit, o.DriverSpeed, o.SeatBelt, o.DrunkenDriving, o.DriversLicense, p.Points 
  FROM Drivers d
JOIN Offences o on (d.IDNumber = o.IDNumber)
JOIN DriverPoints p on (d.IDNumber = p.IDNumber)
WHERE (...) -- Whathever where condition you like
```

This will read everything.

For updating you have to perform 3 distinct updates statements or use a stored procedure or a view, but this really depends on the database you're using.

EDIT: for insert I suggest you to use PreparedStatements

```
String command1 = "INSERT INTO Drivers (IDNumber, FirstName, LastName) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(command1);
ps.setInteger(1, drivID );
ps.setString(2, FName );
ps.setString(3, LName );
ps.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a [`Stored Procedure`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure).

However to make it platform independent, you should use [`ANSI SQL`](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_Is_ANSI_SQL) syntax.

As per BigMike's comment, you could also create a view. [`This`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923543/how-can-i-create-a-view-from-more-than-one-table) will throw more light on creating a view.

Comment: knowing the underlying database will help.but +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert into multiple tables with one statement, so the short answer is no.  You will need three statements to insert into three tables.

Also, your syntax needs to be more like: 
`String command1 = "INSERT INTO Drivers (IDNumber, FirstName, LastName)  VALUES (" + drivID + ", " + FName + ", " + LName + ")";`

Note the addition of the commas and braces.

Also, you can put all of the statements into the one *query*, if that is what you mean.